# Scaling Line Integral Symbols

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, mathspec

I need to use special integral symbols but with Cambria Math they are too small. Is there any way to scale these automatically?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \npolint
        \scpolint
        \pointint
    \]
\end{document}
```

I do have Minion Math which has these integrals and are not too small. If the above equation is not possible, can I use all of integrals from Minion Math but keep everything else from Cambria? I would rather a solution that scales Cambria Math integrals and not have to use Minion Math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are using proper OpenType maths fonts like Cambria Math or Minion Math, you only need the `unicode-math` package. You shouldn't also load the `mathspec` package, which is intended to allow one to employ regular text fonts for maths.

Unfortunately, Cambria Math doesn't contain the necessary integral glyphs in the correct size. While you could simply rescale the existing glyphs using `\resizebox` or some similar approach, the result would not be particularly pleasing - they would look bolder than the other integrals. Your second idea is much better, and can be accomplished with the `range` key of `\setmathfont`, as described in section 4.1 of the `unicode-math` documentation. In particular, you want

```
\setmathfont[ range = {"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C} ]{ Minion Math Regular }
```

You can look up the Unicode ranges in the `unimath-symbols` document, among other places.

Note also that Asana Math, XITS Math, and Lucida Bright Math OT all have the glyphs you need, so if you prefer any of those integral designs, you can use them instead of the ones from Minion Math (personally, though, I like the Minion Math integrals more than the other ones).

Comment: Is there any way to make this work _without_ unicode-math?

Comment: Without `unicode-math` you won't be able to use Cambria Math at all. What problems are you having with it?